# After updates my scanner stopped working over WiFi. How to diagnose?

Tags: 12.10, networking, scanner, hplip

I've been using an HP Officejet 6500 All-in-One for a few years now without any trouble. It is connected wirelessly to my network, for both printing & scanning. However, this week, scanning quit working, apparently as a result of some updates. After trying various things I found that it works fine connected using USB, but that's not a satisfactory fix.

I updated `hplip` to version 3.12.11 and tried reverting to the previous kernel version.  Also, I've tried various scanner programs with varying failure messages such as the following `hp-scan` results:

`3.5.0-20-generic` x86-64 fails with:

```
Opening connection to device...
error: SANE: Invalid argument (code=4)
```

`3.5.0-21-generic` x86-64 fails with:

```
Expecting to read 10.9 MB from scanner.
Reading data: [|                                          ] 0%  0 B   
error: No data read.
Closing device.
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Just realized that I should have made clear that printing still works well, via either wireless or USB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many hours of googling & trying different suggestions, I gave up troubleshooting & uninstalled everything I could find to do with printers & scanners.  Reinstalling seems to have cured the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried several remedies to no avail and I cannot swear that your problem is exactly what I experienced. However I am using MInt13 64 bit, which is based on Ubuntu 12.04. My printer/scanner is HP OfficeJet all-in-one 4620. I downloaded and installed hplip 3.12.11 and the scanner doesn't work. It is not even detected. However I have solved the problem like this:

Getting scanner to work with Mint13 Mate 64bit:

1) If necessary use a text editor as root to add 'hpaio' into '/etc/sane.d/dll.conf', that is if 'hpaio' doesn't appear already.

2) Use a File Manager (Nautilus perhaps), to go to /usr/lib and /usr/lib64, both as administrator/root.

In lib64, make link of directory 'sane', and then cut and paste it into directory /usr/lib; rename the created link as 'sane'. (N.B. There is probably already an empty directory 'sane' in /usr/lib which will first have to deleted or renamed in some meaningless way such as 'sane.original.empty').

This worked ok for me on 08/08/12. Now scanner works fine, either simplescan or xsane.
This is a slightly edited version of my post on the Linux Mint forum dated 09 December 2012. I'm glad to say that someone has reported that it also worked for them!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but hpaio already appears in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf & there is no /usr/lib64 on my system.  ls -all /usr/lib/sane shows -rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   1066 Dec 22 13:21 libsane-hpaio.la
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     22 Dec 22 13:21 libsane-hpaio.so -> libsane-hpaio.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     22 Oct 11 20:05 libsane-hpaio.so.1 -> libsane-hpaio.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 150160 Oct 11 20:05 libsane-hpaio.so.1.0.0